# How to post process JSON logs with Datadog?

Tags: datadog

Our applications log in JSON format. According to Datadog's documentation JSON logs are not processed by pipelines. How can I enrich the JSON logs with an additional field that is based on a different value of that same log line?

I have this line:

```
{"requestUri":"/customers/2934ht8/users"}
```

And I want this line:

```
{"requestUri":"/customers/2934ht8/users","customerId":"2934ht8"}
```

Is this possible with Datadog? I do not want to change our loggers to a the `customerId` to the log output.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. You can do that in a [processing pipeline](https://app.datadoghq.com/logs/pipelines) with a grok parser, but you'll want to configure which attribute the grok parser applies to in the advanced settings ([docs here](https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/processing/parsing/?tab=matcher#advanced-settings)). (By default grok parsers apply to the "message" attribute, but you can configure them to parse any attribute.)

In this case, you'd set the `Extract From` field to `requestUri`. The `Helper Rules` section is not necessary for this. And then in the main `Define Parsing Rules` section, you'll plug in a rule similar to this:

```
parse_customer_id \/customers\/%{notSpace:customerId}\/users
```

or even further

```
parse_customer_id \/%{notSpace}\/%{notSpace:customerId}\/%{notSpace}
```

Comment: I did this. But it does not work since JSON logs are not processed by custom pipelines: `Datadog automatically parses JSON-formatted logs. When your logs are not JSON-formatted, Datadog enables you to add value to your raw logs by sending them through a processing pipeline.` https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/processing/pipelines/#pipelines-goal

Comment: I believe it should still work even after the auto-parsed JSON applies -- are you sure the logs are being routed to the right pipeline? Maybe worth reaching out to Datadog support to get a quick review.

Comment: I also don't see that this works with logs that are already coming in as JSON. But there's an example they publish that shows it should: https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/how-to-categorize-logs/#categorize-logs-based-on-url-patterns

Comment: i have the same issue: to further parse the "parsed" json logs. and also, my json logs already have the "message" field. i'm not sure what to put under "Extract from". I tried "message", "message.message"... nothing works

Comment: Works fine for me in 2022 using the `message` field and a separate already parsed `host` field 

Comment: @Steve would you mind elaborating a bit more? I'm trying to process a JSON message and I'm clueless after reading these replies :)